# Reliable, simple way to keep directories in sync across Linux machines?

Tags: linux, file-synchronization

I've got quite a few machines with quite a few directories that I want to keep in sync. For example, I have `/var/backups` on some servers that I want to take a copy of on a nightly basis. **rsync** is a tool I've been used so far, and initially sounds like a natural choice, because I need the following;

- Synchronization of directories over WAN connections (eg, home server to sync with public web server)
- Easily available in repositories for most Linux distributions (big bonus, makes updating easy)
- Incremental transfers
- Works without any additional ports (just SSH/22) open

I'm running rsync as a standard cronjob at the moment. However, these are the limitations I'm trying to address with a recommendation;

- If /var/backups (or wherever I'm copying from) is empty, or if a file cannot be copied due to permissions, I get no warning or notification.
- For large directory sync's (eg, 3-4 Tb), it's difficult to see the status of that sync at a glance.

Comment: Have you tried the ``--progress`` option to show progress, maybe also couple it with ``--verbose`` and ``--stats`` to print out more details?

Comment: I've just added a suitable tag to your question. While waiting for your dedicated answers, you might wish to browse the [33 other questions tagged `file-synchronization`](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-synchronization), there might be already a solution for you.

Comment: you may consider using a distributed file system with a high number of replicas.  It is not exactly what you asked for, but may serve the purpose rather well.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in the office & can't get past the firewall to post details. But you can now use BitTorrent to efficiently synch almost any kid of device. See http://www.getsync.com/

Answer (score 3):

You may find [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/features/) useful

> Synchronization of directories over WAN connections (eg, home server to sync with public web server)

Check (Main purpose)

> Easily available in repositories for most Linux distributions (big bonus, makes updating easy)

[Check](http://owncloud.org/install/)

> Incremental transfers

[In Progress?](https://github.com/owncloud/mirall/issues/179)

> Works without any additional ports (just SSH/22) open

You can work around this with SSH if you need

> If /var/backups (or wherever I'm copying from) is empty, or if a file cannot be copied due to permissions, I get no warning or notification.

Check (Activity Feed)

> For large directory sync's (eg, 3-4 Tb), it's difficult to see the status of that sync at a glance.

[Check?](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/admin_manual/configuration/configuring_big_file_upload.html)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Gluster (www.gluster.org) ?

Now, wait a sec.  When you look at this thing, if you're like me, it's going to strike you as a really huge thing -- like you're driving to the corner store in your aircraft carrier or something.  But in usage it strikes me as /pretty/ light, despite a few processes running.  I found it really alien to set up the first time (took hours-not-minutes) but subsequent configs from scratch were a matter of minutes after the responses and outputs were familiar.

In its /geo/replicated mode, it seems to watch a tree for changes and then push changed files into a queue for ONE-WAY replication (so far;  bidirectional georeplication is vapoured periodically and then everyone sobers up) to the remote host; I think it's vanilla rsync, but it all kinda handles that in the background.

It will need a few ports open; I'm sorry.  I think you can mitigate that with some port forwarding in a running ssl socket.

Gluster can also be used for live bidirectional synch with X hosts over a LAN, with locks and all that; the geo (rsync) replication doesn't do locking/etc, and is really best used for a remote-backup or 'lukewarm' (mostly-cold) DR solution.

I've advised over the application of gluster to replicate terabytes to a location thousands of kilometers from the source.  The customer replicates back by (manually) disabling the A->B replication and re-enabling the B->A georepl profile already configured.

So.  Grab a paint-by-numbers, allocate some time, take a shot, take a breath, and give it a go?

Answer (score 0):

## [Unison File Synchronizer](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)

Unison is a cross-platform file synchronization tool that allows you to keep two or more replicas of a directory on two or more host machines or disk drives. Some of it's features are:

- Synchronizes files between any pair of machines communicating over either a direct socket link or tunneling over an  `ssh` connection
- Available in Linux repositories ([Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/unison),  [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Unison), [Fedora](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/10802416/dir/fedora_4/com/unison-2.27.57-1.fc4.rf.x86_64.rpm.html), [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/unison/), [etc...](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download.html))
- Incremental transfers similar to `rsync`:

> Transfers of small updates to large files are optimized using a compression protocol similar to rsync
>
> Works without additional ports<sup>1</sup>
>
> For the additional requirements in the question:

- Displays detailed status through both texual and graphical interfaces
- Displays warnings in console window or as an advisory pop-up window

---

<sup>1</sup>On Linux. Might require additional configuration on Windows

Comment: I considered Unison for my own stuff, I had to say.  90% of the time it runs really well, too.  For the 10% where one has to dive in for something, though, we decided to skip it.

If the user can handle the care and feeding that's very-occasionally (read: monitor this!) required, then it stands as a great user-space option over vanilla rsync.